# What are the best sites or free software for rephrasing sentences?

Tags: phd, thesis, plagiarism, writing-style

While writing my thesis, I'm looking for some sites or free software that can help in rephrasing some sentences used in scientific papers. Any recommendation? And is it effective to use such sites to avoid copy-paste sentences?

Comment: A tool for people who are too lazy to even plagiarize properly? I doubt it exists.

Comment: @ThomasS, [on the Internet, everything exists](https://www.google.ru/search?q=sentence+rephraser). They are of inferior quality, though, at least the ones I could test in 5 minutes. And when I say 'inferior', I mean, 'incoherent and unreadable word scramble'.

Comment: @Thomas note that there is no evidence the OP is plagiarizing. They may wish to avoid overusing the quote-unquote citations.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that you are not aware of how misguided and offensive your question is to me, jakebeal (I'm guessing), and other educators reading and posting on this site, so I thought it's worth saying something about that.

The point is that writing a thesis is part of a journey of learning in which a person studies a subject, thinks about it very hard and in great depth, and creates a work that represents their own unique point of view on the subject. The writing is an essential part of this process: as educators everywhere know and understand, **each word and each sentence in the thesis must be individually chosen, crafted, thought about and written by you, the writer of the thesis, in order for true learning to take place**. This may seem like an exaggeration, but I assure you I'm dead serious. (This principle of course makes necessary allowance for names and for properly attributed verbatim quotes.) Keep in mind that when I speak about learning I am referring to a process where you master several complex skills, not only learning about the specific subject you are writing about, but also learning how to think critically, how to communicate complex ideas effectively, and how to write well. These are valuable skills that will serve you well long after you have forgotten most of the technical details related to the topic of the thesis.

Now, if you accept that what I wrote above is true (and I hope that you do), then several consequences follow:

1. The entire concept of "rephrasing" or "paraphrasing" needs to be thrown out the window. In my opinion these are misguided notions that represent the dangerous mindset that taking words written by another person and just applying some cosmetic or algorithmic changes to them, with the only goal being to avoid "copy-paste sentences," is an acceptable practice. It isn't, because it skips the part where you actually **think about the content** of what you are writing, which is the most important and central part of the learning process (and the part that is the most difficult and makes our brain hurt, and that lazy people are always looking for ways to avoid). So yes, in your thesis, it may make sense in certain places to summarize some thoughts or comments from the scientific literature - that is absolutely okay. But instead of thinking about this as "rephrasing" you should think about this as "I've thought hard about how to communicate a complex set of ideas presented by another author, and here is the best way I've found to explain what I understood this author was saying."
2. If you use any method whatsoever for going around the difficult part of thinking about what you are writing - whether it's by paying someone else to write part of your thesis, or using sentence rephrasing software, assuming it exists - **you are cheating yourself**, by depriving yourself of one of the main benefits that you are supposed to be deriving from writing a thesis.
3. Using such software or other means to avoid doing the work that is specifically assumed to be an integral part of writing a thesis is also likely to be viewed by others reading your thesis as dishonest and a form of cheating.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with attempting to use some sort of "rephrasing software" is that proper rephrasing is not just repainting a piece of text in order to avoid some technical definition of plagiarism.

Instead, proper rephrasing is taking a set of ideas, incorporating them into your own thinking, and then explaining your thinking (which now incorporates those ideas) in the context of your own work.  No mere piece of software can do that work for you---if it was sophisticated enough to do such thinking, you would need to credit it as a co-author.

If you are worried about accidentally repeating phrasing, I would recommend doing the following:

1. Carefully read the entire source that you want to adapt ideas from.
2. Do something entirely different for at least an hour.
3. Write down your understanding of the material you read and how it applies in the context of your own work, entirely from memory and without looking at the original source.
4. Now return to the source and see if there are any important mistakes you made, things that you overlooked, or phrases that you accidentally repeated.

It is easy, especially for an inexperienced writer, to get stuck in thinking that a nice presentation of material is "the only way" that it can be written.  Taking that palette-cleansing time and avoiding looking at the original will make it extremely likely that you will end up truly presenting in your own words.

Answer (score 1):

Ethical concerns with using such "rephrasing" software have been address thoroughly so far. However, I would like to focus on something that has been alluded to in some of the answers and this is the information processing aspect of the thesis experience.

When you are forced to analyze and develop ways to express other's ideas in your own words it is highly beneficial in helping you to retain the incredible amount of information you consume when writing a thesis. This is critical because understanding what you know from having to express yourself helps you to know your thesis inside and out. As you wrestle with each reference and idea it sticks with you for literally the rest of your life. This only happened because you actually thought about and expressed it.

If this process is skipped through the use of software you would not really know what you wrote and why. You would not be able to see the connections between the various ideas and themes of your paper. Lastly, when you are asked to defend your thesis you would be completely unprepared and unable to answer many of the questions of your committee.

I do not want to downplay the ethical concerns here but just bring to light a perspective from a psychological viewpoint.