# Getting caught by plagiarism checkers

Tags: citations, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

I've been writing for people but I'm sick of a plagiarism checker known as 1text. It gives plagiarism reports for words and I don't understand why a word can't be the same on different websites. Can anyone help me find an alternative to 1text?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "I've been writing for people..."?

Comment: Means that I write for clients***

Comment: Does it mean you do homework that is assigned to students? Are the "clients" students at school or university?

Comment: Those are students for different universities

Comment: This sounds like you are aiding academic misconduct. If that is so, then this really isn't the place to come for help in doing it. Why would plagiarism detection be an issue for "honest" work?

Comment: What's the reason for the self-plagiarism tag on this post?

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/63719/68109

Comment: Sounds like the perfect storm combination of homework-for-hire with plagiarism. Add some fabricated data and the academic misconductometer hits the jackpot. </irony off>

Comment: I hope your question is about false positives, otherwise it sounds like "I've gained too much weight, I need new scales".

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a plagiarism checker on the author's side. Just follow the rules outlined by the institution/publisher, and that's it. Really!

It is perfectly normal for plagiarism checkers to catch some text as potentially plagiarised. This is not problematic, as the checker is only there to help the grader or the publisher to detect plagiarism.

For instance, my last IEEE paper had ~10% of the paper flagged as potentially plagiarised (the author gets a report). This was not problematic at all - it was mostly the bibliography, a few multi-word technical terms that were already in use, and some standard phrases. None of that is actually plagiarism, so there was no problem.

Note that it you "write for people", you should let the client know that he/she has to mark the parts that you wrote as not written by himself/herself, otherwise your client commits plagiarism regardless of whether the text is new or not (assuming an academic context). Plagiarism is, roughly, declaring the work of others as your own one.